# Change the contents of the container

Tags: flutter

I have a space on the screen containing a temperature indicator and two buttons "temperature" and "humidity". I want that when I click on the button labeled "humidity", the space will be replaced by another one in which I will have a humidity indicator. How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StatefulWidget` its `setState()` method.

Here is an article: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactivity

Here is a more specific example:

```
class IndicatorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const IndicatorWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IndicatorWidgetState createState() => _IndicatorWidgetState();
}

class _IndicatorWidgetState extends State<IndicatorWidget> {
  bool showTemperature = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      if (showTemperature) Text('Temperature XXX'),
      if (!showTemperature) Text('Humidity YYY'),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  showTemperature = true;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Temperature')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  showTemperature = false;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Humidity')),
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```